# Ignoring a new file with vue's dev server

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I'm using the `pre-build-webpack` plugin to merge several json files into 1 json array every time I start my app (`npm run serve` or `npm run build`), but the problem is that it gets caught in an infinite webpack compile loop in when I start the development server. I managed to find a solution to the problem by using the `watch-ignore-webpack-plugin` plugin, which initially seemed to have resolved the issue - webpack will now compile everything twice (it seems) and then it's good to go and I can access my local server. But the problem now is that when I visit localhost:8080 there's nothing. The screen's blank and there's nothing being `console.log()`ed, so I don't know what to do anymore.

If anyone's seen anything like this or know how to fix it, please let me know. If you require any additional info, also let me know.

Versions:

- vue: 2.6.10 (as seen in `package.json`)
- vue-cli: 3.11.0 (running `vue -V` in cmd)
- pre-build-webpack: 0.1.0
- watch-ignore-webpack-plugin: 1.0.0
- webpack-log: 3.0.1

vue.config.js (with everything irrelevant removed):

```
const WebpackPreBuildPlugin = require('pre-build-webpack');
const WatchIgnorePlugin = require('watch-ignore-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new WebpackPreBuildPlugin(() => {

        const fs = require('fs');
        const glob = require('glob');
        const log = require('webpack-log')({ name: 'ATTENTION!' });
        const output = [];
        const exclude = [];

        glob('./src/components/mods/**/*.json', (err, paths) => {
          paths.forEach(path => {
            const content = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf-8'));
            const pathSplit = path.split('/');
            const modFolderName = pathSplit[pathSplit.length - 2]

            if(!output.filter(val => val.id === content.id)[0]) {
              if(exclude.indexOf(modFolderName) === -1) {
                output.push(content);
              } else {
                log.warn(`SKIPPING CONTENTS OF "${modFolderName}"`);
              }
            } else {
              log.error(`MOD WITH ID "${content.id}" ALREADY EXISTS!`);
              process.exit(0);
            }
          });

          // If I take out this line, the infinite loop doesn't occur, but then, of 
          // course, I don't get my merged json file either.
          fs.writeFileSync('./src/config/modules/layoutConfig.json', JSON.stringify(output));
        });

      }),
      // Neither of the blow paths work.
      new WatchIgnorePlugin([/\layoutConfig.json$/]),
      // new WatchIgnorePlugin(['./src/config/modules/layoutConfig.json']),
    ]
  }
};
```